# UISwipeGestureRecognizer: How to force the touchesMoved stop and go into touchesEnded

Tags: xcode, ios5, rotation, uigesturerecognizer, touchesmoved

I am working with UISwipeGestureRecognizer. I have the following problem. When I touch a square, it starts rotating.When I stop touching it, it stops rotating. I would like to do, with a timer, when it pass 10 seconds of touch, the square automatically stops rotating. I found a solution but I think that is it not clean. 
Do you have any idea to pass automatically from the method:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

to the method:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I was using this code:

```
  - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
if ([self state] == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
      [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan];
       NSLog(@"Algo Began");

   } 

    if ([[event touchesForGestureRecognizer:self] count] > 1)
    {
        [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ];
        NSLog(@"Algo Fail");

    }


    if (chowMuch==50) {
        //[self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed  ]; 
        [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized  ]; 


        NSLog(@"Algo falla que pasara");
    }

   else {
      [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged];
       NSLog(@"Algo changed");

}
}
```

The method is all the time executing the `NSLog(@"Algo changed")`, that means that when I touch the square the state is UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged, but when the `chowMuch` is 50, this finish. Do you have any idea to pass to the `touchesEnded`

Answer (score -1):

Try removing and re-adding the subview that receives (or responds to) the touches.

Since someone downvoted the answer: Above does cancel the gesture even if the user never lifts the finger. I have looked for a while but could not find another solution.

Of course this is not suited for more complex tasks.
See also [UIScrollView and cancel a zooming pinch gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234945/uiscrollview-and-cancel-a-zooming-pinch-gesture/15603777#15603777)